# Linked list stack Pop method

Tags: c#, list, stack

I am trying to create a Linked list Stack with Pop and Push functionality. The Push method is working but the Pop isn't. I can't figure out where to return the value within it goes, I think it should work when that is sorted out (sorry for the poor wording).

Here is my code:

```
class Program
{

    int nextFree;
    int End;
    int Start;
    Names[] Stack;
    Names greg = new Names();
    Names matt = new Names();
    Names jack = new Names();
    Names fred = new Names();

    public struct Names
    {
        public Int32 pointer;
        public string data;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Program prog = new Program();
        do
        {
            prog.DisplayMenu();
        }
        while (true);
    }

    public void DisplayMenu()
    {
        Int32 userInput = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("Linear Stack");
        Console.WriteLine("1: Add to stack");
        Console.WriteLine("2: Delete from stack");
        userInput = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


        switch (userInput)
        {
            case 1:
                this.Push();
                break;
            case 2:
                this.Pop();
                break;
        }

    }

     public Program() 
    {
       Stack = new Names[6];

        greg.data = "Greg";
        greg.pointer = 1;

        matt.data = "Matt";
        matt.pointer = 2;

        jack.data = "Jack";
        jack.pointer = 3;

        fred.data = "Fred";
        fred.pointer = -1;

        Stack[0] = greg;
        Stack[1] = matt;
        Stack[2] = jack;
        Stack[3] = fred;
        nextFree = 4;
        End = 5;
        Start = 0;
    }


     public string Pop()
     {

         string value = string.Empty;

         if (nextFree == -1)
         {
             Console.WriteLine("Stack is empty");
             Console.ReadLine();
         }
         else
         {
             Names thisNode = Stack[End];
             int temp = End;
             End = thisNode.pointer;
             thisNode.pointer = nextFree;
             nextFree = temp;
         }
         this.ListAllNames();
         return value;
     }

     public void Push()
     {
         if (nextFree >= Stack.Length)
         {
             Console.WriteLine("Stackoverflow, to many elements for the stack");
             Console.ReadLine();
         }
         else
         {
             Console.WriteLine("Enter a name to be added");
             string input = Console.ReadLine();
             Stack[nextFree].data = input;
             Stack[nextFree].pointer = End;
             End = nextFree;
             nextFree++;     
         }
            this.ListAllNames();
     }


     public void ListAllNames()
     {
         foreach (Names name in Stack)
         {
             Console.WriteLine("Name:" + name.data);
         }
     }



 }
}
```

Comment: Homework assignment? (If so, there are some other things you could do to improve your code).

Comment: If it's supposed to be a linked list, why are you using an array?

Comment: @R0MANARMY Yeah it is, I'm sure there are quite a few things as, let's be honest, it isn't that well coded :P. I just need to get the Pop method working then I'm gonna start tidying it up and making it more efficient if I can.

Comment: @ObliviousSage It's just the way my teacher wants us to do it

Comment: You can implement the stack using a linked list, or you can implement it using an array, but you can't do both. You need to make sure you understand what your instructor wants, because if they want a linked list and you use an array, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @R0MANARMY I'm going to add it in now

Comment: @user2852418 If you want, we can just create a room and work through this (probably better than leaving it up as a question).

Comment: @ObliviousSage I know it's not the ideal way to do this, it's a linked list within an Array (I think that's how he described it), however it's the way our teacher has told us to do it.

Comment: Why not enclose all the relevant code into a `Stack` class?

Comment: @R0MANARMY How do I do that?

Comment: Are you sure your teacher doesn't want 2 separate programs, one that implements a stack using an array, and one that uses a linked list?

Comment: @ObliviousSage Yeah, he wanted one like that and then one Linear which I finished about 30 mins ago.

Comment: I created one [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/43375/20645103?tab=general), you should be able to join the room, paste your code and go from there.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend reading [Eric Lippert's Immutable Stack](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/12/04/immutability-in-c-part-two-a-simple-immutable-stack.aspx) article. It will give you some really interesting tips on implementation.

Here's the code from it:

```
public interface IStack<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    IStack<T> Push(T value);
    IStack<T> Pop();
    T Peek();
    bool IsEmpty { get; }
}

public sealed class Stack<T> : IStack<T>
{
    private sealed class EmptyStack : IStack<T>
    {
        public bool IsEmpty { get { return true; } }
        public T Peek() { throw new Exception("Empty stack"); }
        public IStack<T> Push(T value) { return new Stack<T>(value, this); }
        public IStack<T> Pop() { throw new Exception("Empty stack"); }
        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() { yield break; }
        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { return this.GetEnumerator(); }
    }
    private static readonly EmptyStack empty = new EmptyStack();
    public static IStack<T> Empty { get { return empty; } }
    private readonly T head;
    private readonly IStack<T> tail;
    private Stack(T head, IStack<T> tail)
    {
        this.head = head;
        this.tail = tail;
    }
    public bool IsEmpty { get { return false; } }
    public T Peek() { return head; }
    public IStack<T> Pop() { return tail; }
    public IStack<T> Push(T value) { return new Stack<T>(value, this); }
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        for(IStack<T> stack = this; !stack.IsEmpty ; stack = stack.Pop())
            yield return stack.Peek();
    }
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {return this.GetEnumerator();}
}
```

Comment: If he's just looking for any implementation of a `Stack` he can use the library implementation.  The whole point of the question is that he has his own implementation, and wants to know what's wrong with it.  This doesn't answer that.

Comment: I understand that, I was showing him an example of a simple, ground-up solution to a `Stack` collection. This way he could consider changing his based on ideas provided within.

Answer (score 0):

You're not being very *object-oriented*. As Niklaus Wirth pointed out:

> Objects = Data + Algorithms

You need to *encapsulate* things, like this:

```
public class LinkedListStack<T>
{
  /// <summary>
  /// indicates whether or not the stack contains data
  /// </summary>
  public bool HasData { get { return this.Top != null ; } }

  /// <summary>
  /// The topmost stack frame
  /// </summary>
  private Node Top { get ; set; }

  /// <summary>
  /// constructor
  /// </summary>
  public LinkedListStack()
  {
    this.Top   = null ;
    return ;
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// constructor: initializes the stack with the provied contents.
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="data"></param>
  public LinkedListStack( IEnumerable<T> data ) : this()
  {
    if ( data == null ) throw new ArgumentNullException("data") ;
    foreach ( T datum in data )
    {
      Push(datum) ;
    }
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// remove the top item from the stack and return it
  /// </summary>
  /// <returns></returns>
  public T Pop()
  {
    if ( this.Top == null ) throw new InvalidOperationException("Can't pop an empty stack!");
    Node top = this.Top ;
    this.Top = top.Next ;
    return top.Payload ;
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// push an item onto the stack
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="datum"></param>
  public void Push( T datum )
  {
    this.Top = new Node( datum , this.Top ) ;
    return ;
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// private helper class (our stack frame)
  /// </summary>
  private class Node
  {
    public Node Next    ;
    public T    Payload ;
    public Node( T payload ) : this(payload,null)
    {
      return ;
    }
    public Node( T payload , Node next )
    {
      this.Next = next ;
      this.Payload = payload ;
      return ;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: :s/ `this.Next = null ;` / `this.Next = next ;`

Comment: @Shanthakumar, you should propose an edit, rather than commenting. It boosts your rep (see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287956/what-are-so-incentives-for-editing-a-post)